# removing virtualmin and webmin from remote CentOS 7 server

Tags: centos, rpm, uninstall, webmin

Webmin and Virtualmin were recently installed using rpm packages on a remote CentOS 7 server.  How do I uninstall them?

I have googled this, but all the results are either so old as to be obsolete or do not pertain to rpm files, or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove rpm packages you can use rpm's -e flag. Firstly find the name of the rpm you have installed;

`rpm -qa | egrep -i "webmin|virtualmin"`

Then remove the package from the name that you see from above;

`rpm -e $packagename`

Comment: So now list each of those packages after ```rpm -e```, for example; ```rpm -e wbm-virtualmin-svn-5.0-1.noarch webmin-1.720-1.noarch``` but with each package listed.

Comment: for doing what you told in single command using yum remove see http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-uninstall-webmin-on-centos-6-3/

Comment: I just used the method in the link & it worked. I suggest you update your answer (I didn't edit answer because it's already shown as correct).